# Position of the modal box

Tags: javascript, user-interface, modal-dialog, webix

I have a modal box created in Webix. How can I specify its position on the page?

```
webix.confirm({    
  title: "Title",
  ok:"Yes", cancel:"No",        
  text:"Are you sure?",
});
```

I didn't find properties such as `align` or something. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.
[Snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/c4c16787)

Comment: According to http://docs.webix.com/desktop__message_boxes.html you can set the width and height of the box using width and height properties.  Note that this confirm box is not modal (does not prevent workflow on the rest of the application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible to customize any element of Webix Scheduler.
All you need to do is to redefine the needed attributes of the related css class in the `<style>` block of your page.
for example your in case you should  redefine the left and  top of webix_modal_box class like this:

```css
<style type="text/css">
  .webix_modal_box{
    left:100px !important;
    top:100px !important;
  }
</style>
```

this is a [working snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/4e79e12b)